# How is 172ms block propagation possible?

Tags: network, transaction-propagation

[Here](https://www.coindesk.com/ethereum-scaling-fix-cuts-time-to-create-a-block-in-half-test-finds) you can read that avg block propagation time is 172 milliseconds till it is shared all over the blockchain.

How is this even possible?

You can clearly see that reaching some locations takes much more time:
https://wondernetwork.com/pings

Moreover the message will need to do multiple hops though out different nodes and take time for miners to re-broadcast it.

Comment: "On the internet you can find that avg block propagation time" Please cite the sources where you find such "facts".

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa  Added the link to the source in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockchain advisory firm Akomba Labs ran bloXroute’s “Blockchain Distribution Network” (BDN) on an Ethereum node in Singapore between Nov. 11 and Nov. 27, finding that average block propagation time – the time a block needs to be produced and shared throughout a blockchain – dropped to 172 milliseconds, less than half the current average time of 360 milliseconds.

You are reading a paid PR buff from not so reliable source. Maybe the named company has achieved something, maybe not. But the source is a press release aimed to sell services of the named company, not research, so there is no worth even to discuss if this is true or not.